# An I/O operation initiated by the Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I keep getting this error on my PC:

> An I/O operation initiated by the Registry failed unrecoverably. The Registry could not read in, or write out, or flush, one of the files that contain the system's image of the Registry.

I've seen other cases on the web, but there is one difference. This error won't go away with a restart.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: probably a corrupt regkey!

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows is failing to write one of the core files of the Registry, and is showing this message. Try using `regedit` to make a new value in one of the registry hives, and see if it comes up with that error. Then, restart and see if the value is still there.